# length of a String

Tags: java, methods, if-statement, invoke, bluej

The member ID consists of a unique sequence of letters and digits* of length at most 10 and the pin number consists of a sequence of four digits, i have wrote tow methods checkId and checkPassword to compare the length and then i called them in the Constructor. but the code seems not working fine

```
public class Test
    {

    private String yourName;
    private String yourId;
    private int password;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Test
     */
    public Test(String yourName, String yourId, int password)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.yourName = yourName;
        this.yourId = yourId;
        this.password = password;
        checkPassword();
        checkId();
    }

    private void checkId()
    {
       int length; 
       length = yourId.length();
       if (length >= 10){
           System.out.print("the length must be less than 10, please change it");
        }
    }

    private void checkPassword()
    {
        int length;
        length = password.length();
        if (length != 4 ){
            System.out.println("must be at 4");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of it isn't working?

Comment: make your password string, its declared as an int primitive :P

Answer (score 4):

The variable `password` is of type `int`. Types such as these are called primitives, so they have no methods such as `length()`. You could do `Integer.toString(password).length()` instead.

Comment: or just declare password as a string, password an int-- doesnt really make sense to me :P

Comment: True, though he might find it easier to manipulate it as an int; he said it was a 4 digit pin.

Comment: okay now i understood,  what about  if (length != 4 ), but the problem with this is that the object will be created in both cases

Comment: can i declare as a String, but its only four digit long, numbers only

Comment: An int will guarantee that your password is actually numeric. If you wish to allow passwords such as `0000` or `0101`, you could do instead `if (password >= 0 && password < 10000)`

Comment: the length of the password must be at 4 digit, 4 numbers only not less then four or greater then, i ve tried what you told me about but it did work

Comment: Well, you could interpret `0` as `0`, `00`, `000`, `0000`, `00000`, etc. Which method did you try, and how did it not work?

Comment: private void checkPassword()
    {
        
        Integer.toString(password).length();
        if (length > 4){
            System.out.println("must be at 4");
        }
    }

Comment: It would help to be more specific.

Comment: if you look at my code, The member ID consists of a unique sequence of letters and digits* of length at most 10 and the Password consists of a sequence of four digits,  i have wrote tow methods checkId and checkPassword to compare the length and then i called them in the Constructor. but the code seems not working fine

Comment: Simply calling `Integer.toString(password).length()` won't do anything. You need to assign it to your `int length`.